# Approximation of a polynomial via histogram

Tags: probability, histogram, approximation, density-estimation

Note: I originally tried to pose this question generally, without discussing the specific type of stochastic process. I hope that this can still be an interesting question generally.

Assume that we have a point process $\Phi$ with support on some bounded complete space $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\Phi$ is characterized by the intensity measure $\Lambda(\cdot)$, which has intensity function $\lambda(\cdot)$. This means that $\Lambda(B)=\int_B \lambda(x)dx=\mathbb{E}[\Phi(B)]$.

Now that the necessary notation has been introduced, here is my question: suppose that I observe a realization of $\Phi$, which we write as a set $\phi=\{\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_n\}$ of points (each of which have some x-valued coordinate). Further suppose that we believe that the intensity function (which we can think of as the data generating process for $\phi$) is of the form $f(x,\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^k\alpha_i x^i$.

If we then plot a histogram of $\phi$, can we "recover'' the coefficients $\alpha_i$ from this histogram, up to some closeness? More formally if $n$ gets very large, and the number of bins $b$ gets very large (or equivalently, the bin width goes to 0), can we fit some polynomial $ f(x,\hat\alpha)=\sum_{i=0}^k\hat\alpha_i x^i$ from the histogram such that $\forall \epsilon>0$,  $|\alpha_i-\hat\alpha_i|<\epsilon$?

This is basically a density fitting problem. Intuitively, I think that given enough data, we should be able to recover the coefficients. I am not interested in a KDE approach, rather just if there is some theorem, or paper that you are aware of that demonstrates this result.

Please note I also asked on mathematics stack exchange the exact same question.

Comment: I cannot discern anything stochastic in your description: except in a degenerate sense, polynomial functions are not stochastic processes.  Maybe you are thinking of some of the $x^i$ and/or some of the $\alpha_i$ as being random variables?  Even then this wouldn't be a stochastic process except in the trivial sense that any random variable could be considered a "process" on a singleton parameter set.  Something essential must be missing from the description.

Comment: Also, can you describe the kind of stochastic processes you have in mind? Are they continuous distributions with a density function? If the process were supported on an interval, the answer would be simple, with the help of Bernstein polynomials. Otherwise, essentially the Glivenko--Cantelli theorem leads to a similar result.   Edit your question to respond to this and the other comment.

Comment: @PeterO. I updated now. I think that the bernstein polynomials approach should be what I am looking for, but I can't formalize it concretely in my head. The intensity function is indeed a continuous function on a closed interval. Basically my issue is the identifiability of the $\alpha_j$. Simply put, under what conditions can we create an "optimal" histogram such that we can identify the parameters of the functional representation of the original data generating process.

Comment: The short answer is no in general, unless you make additional assumptions about the point process.  The problem is that any single realization can differ (dramatically) from the process itself.  What would make this work are assumptions tantamount to supposing your process is a simple random sample from the density $f,$ placing you in the domain of parametric estimation, for which you can apply standard results.

Comment: Can I hope for this to work, in expectation? That makes sense that for a single realization, I have no hope. But what about if I thought about the histograms of many realizations (not sure how that would practically work out, perhaps the average bin values or something like that).

Comment: @whuber or perhaps more subtly, can I simply hope to estimate the parameters of interest from this histogram such that  they are consistent and unbiased?

Comment: Not from a single realization.  But this raises the question of what you might mean by "as $n$ gets large."  There are only two ways to accomplish this: re-run the process independently many times or increase the domain over which you observe the process.  Which do you have in mind?  What actual statistical situation are you trying to model?

Comment: @whuber You know what, I think I have been just thinking about this whole thing the wrong way, and therefore I won't waste any more of your time. Thank you so much though, I really appreciate it.